# how to set password on jsPdf library while download PDF

Tags: pdf, jspdf

```
<script>
```

const button = document.getElementById('download-button');

function generatePDF() {

```
   // Choose the element that your content will be rendered to.
   const element = document.getElementById('invoice');
   // Choose the element and save the PDF for your user.
   var opt = {
    filename:     'test.pdf',
    image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1.2 },
    html2canvas:  { scale: 2 },
    jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait'}
  };
```

// Choose the element and save the PDF for your user.
html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();

}

button.addEventListener('click', generatePDF);